# Why this o/P...Server Upload Failed

Tags: c++, c, linux, bash, ternary-operator

Please tell me why iam always getting "Server Upload Failed!" in the code 
given below.

```
int rval = 28;
char *return_str=NULL;

return_str = strdup((rval!=28) ? ("Server Upload Failed!") : ("Server TimeOut Reached!"));
printf(" return_str : %s\n", return_str);

Output that iam getting is ====> Server Upload Failed! . I want to know why it is not giving
"Server TimeOut Reached!" as output .
```

Platform : Linux , gcc-compiler

Comment: On gcc 4.5.2, ubuntu, it runs as expected (output: `return_str : Server TimeOut Reached!`) are you sure you're not running a stale version? Have you tried to clean/rebuild?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks correct to me, once I read it a couple of extra times. It should generate the latter string ("Server TimeOut Reached").

Not sure why you would ever need to call `strdup()` on a static string, instead of just using the literal directly. One case would be if there sometimes a need for a more dynamic string I guess, so whoever receives the value assumes it's dynamic and takes ownership.